# How to access connection string from Class Library in Blazor app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-7.0

In my solution I have three projects:

- Class Library (business logic layer / data access)
- Blazor WebAssembly App (client app)
- Console App (client app)

My Class Library have all the business logic: **Data Context**, **Interfaces**, **Models** and **Repositories** and also **database** as Sqlite file.

Now I want to pass connection string to those two client projects.
In Blazor app as far as I know you have to register a service to properly access database. How can I pass a connection string (which is described in Class library) to `options.UseSqlite();` in Blazor app and to console app? How to re-use options defined in Class library instead of defining another one in Blazor app?

What's the best way to access connection string from class library to any client app in that matter? What are the best practises to follow SOLID principles in this case?

### DataContext.cs in Class Library

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Schowek.Library.Models;

namespace Schowek.Library.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
        {

        }
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Catalog>? Catalogs { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<Item>? Items { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=./Data/app.db");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Program.cs in Blazor App

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Schowek.Client.BlazorWASM;
using Schowek.Library.Data;
using Schowek.Library.Interfaces;
using Schowek.Library.Repositories;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite();
});
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICatalogRepository, CatalogRepository>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

### appsettings.json in Class Library

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevelopmentConnection": "DataSource=./Data/app.db;Cache=Shared"
  }
}
```

Comment: You want your connection string to be accessible in Blazor WASM app? This is a security risk, since this will be available for any user to read..

Comment: Which bit of your application is using the DBContext?  If this is WASM it should be backend API, not the SPA running in the client browser.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, and you want to share the connection string between ClassLibrary and Blazor client applications,
In your case, create a Class in your Blazor project or another common project that is used by everyone. For example: with the name `'AppConfigurations'` and the string property named `DevelopmentConnection`.

Now, in the `Program.cs` file where you register your services, add your `appsettings.json` file to the 'AppConfigurations.cs' created above you will be able to parse the file.

You can do the parsing like this:

```cs
var configs = new AppConfigurations();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(configs);
    
builder.Services.AddSingleton(configs);
```

Now the connection string in your `appsetting.json` file is loaded into `'configs'`, and injected into the project scope
you can use.